# SharePoint 2013 Change the look - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'm trying the "Change a Look" feature for my SharePoint Team Site, after pressing "Try it out". I received this error: "The system cannot find the file specified". I tried with other styles, too but none of them working. Am I missing anything ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your alternate access mappings are setup correctly. I had this issue and it was solved because i was accessing it on the wrong url.